# Keeping a string without over writing it throughout the program in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.4

I'm trying to make a program that stores a user's recipe, using a tkinter gui to do so. I need to make a way to keep track of what is inputted, and store it in a text file. I have tried using lists to no avail, and think that using a string is the way forward, but have run into a problem - each time I try to add to the string, it over writes and doesn't keep the data from before. I have tried to use

```
mystring.join(a + b + etc)
```

but that didnt work, and my new code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *

number_people = 1
itemslist = ''
itemslist1 = ''

def script ():   # Puts main body of program into a function so that it can be re-run #

    global number_people
    number_people = 1

    global itemslist, itemslist1
    itemslist = ''
    itemslist1 = ''

    #### MAIN ####

    fake_window = Tk()                          #                                   #                             
    new_recipe_window = fake_window             # Opens window, allows it be closed #
    start_window = fake_window                  #                                   #
    start_window.title("Recipe Book Task")      #                                   #


    #### MAIN ####  



    ### Functions ###

    def close (x):

        global start_window
        global new_recipe_window
        (x).withdraw()

    def moreitems ():

        a = item_box.get()
        b = quantity_units_box.get()
        c = len(a)
        if a == '':
            pass

        elif b == '':
            pass

        else:
            item_box.delete(0,c)
            quantity_units_box.delete(0,c)
            global itemslist
            global itemslist1
            itemslist1 = itemslist + a + ', ' + b + ', '
            print ("Items list =", itemslist1)


    def new_recipe ():

        new_recipe_window = Tk()
        new_recipe_window.title("New Recipe")
        close(start_window)

        recipe_name_label = Label(new_recipe_window, text="Recipe Name: ")
        recipe_name_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        recipe_name_box = Entry(new_recipe_window)
        recipe_name_box.grid(row=0, column=1)

        def continue_1 ():

            global check_box
            check_box = recipe_name_box.get()
            if check_box == '':
                pass

            else:
                global itemslist
                global itemslist1
                itemslist1 = itemslist + check_box + ', '
                print (itemslist1)
                continue_button_1.destroy()

                item_label = Label(new_recipe_window, text="Ingredient: ")
                item_label.grid(row=1, column=0)

                global item_box
                item_box = Entry(new_recipe_window)
                item_box.grid(row=1, column=1)

                quantity_units_label = Label(new_recipe_window, text="Quantity and Units: ")
                quantity_units_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

                global quantity_units_box
                quantity_units_box = Entry(new_recipe_window)
                quantity_units_box.grid(row=2, column=1)

                def continue_2 ():
                    check_box_1 = item_box.get()
                    check_box_2 = quantity_units_box.get()
                    if check_box_1 == '':
                        pass

                    elif check_box_2 == '':
                        pass

                    else:
                        global itemslist
                        itemslist.join(check_box_1)
                        itemslist.join(check_box_2)

                        continue_button_2.destroy()
                        more_items.destroy()

                        add_people_label = Label(new_recipe_window, text="Choose amount of people")
                        add_people_label.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

                        def add ():
                            global number_people
                            number_people += 1
                            num_people_label.config(text="Number of people: " + str(number_people))

                        def minus ():
                            global number_people
                            if number_people > 1:
                                number_people -= 1
                                num_people_label.config(text="Number of people: " + str(number_people))

                        def finish ():
                            itemslist.join(str(number_people))
                            print("ItemsList = " + itemslist)
                            saveFile = open("Recipe_Book.txt", "a")
                            saveFile.write(itemslist + '\n')
                            saveFile.close
                            close(new_recipe_window)
                            script()

                        num_people_label = Label(new_recipe_window, text="Number of people: " + str(number_people))
                        num_people_label.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

                        add_people_button = Button(new_recipe_window, text="+")
                        add_people_button.grid(row=5, column=1)
                        add_people_button.config(command=add)

                        minus_people_button = Button(new_recipe_window, text="-")
                        minus_people_button.grid(row=5, column=0)
                        minus_people_button.config(command=minus)

                        finish_button = Button(new_recipe_window, text="Finish")
                        finish_button.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2)
                        finish_button.config(command=finish)


                continue_button_2 = Button(new_recipe_window, text="Continue...")
                continue_button_2.grid(row=3, column=0)
                continue_button_2.config(command=continue_2)

                more_items = Button(new_recipe_window, text="Add another item", command=moreitems)
                more_items.grid(row=3, column=1)



        continue_button_1 = Button(new_recipe_window, text="Continue...")
        continue_button_1.grid(row=1, column=0)
        continue_button_1.config(command=continue_1)


    new_recipe = Button(start_window, text="New Recipe", command=new_recipe)
    new_recipe.grid(row=0, column=0)


script()
```

So to recap, my question is how do I keep the string itemslist and itemslist1 from being overwritten, or is there another way I can do this?

**EDIT FOR AAAANTOINE**

I was about to clarify for you what I wanted, but I just figured out what I was doing wrong, thanks for your help, you taught me what .join does, thanks.

Comment: Please shorten your code to the minimum needed.

Comment: To append 3 strings, `a`, `b`, & `c` to an existing string `s`, you'd need to use either `s = s + a + b + c` or `s = s + ''.join([a, b, c])`. As you can see, what actually happens is a new string is being created and then its contents are assigned to `s`. That's necessary because strings are immutable -- unchangeable -- in Python.

Comment: @martineau thanks for clarifying that, I think I know what the problem is now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code never actually assigns to `itemslist` other than at the beginning of `script()`.  The only time it ever appears on the left side of the assignment operator is when it's being initialized.

You can probably change all instances of `itemslist1` to `itemslist` and have a working program.

### Edit

On further review, I suspect that you think str.join(v) appends string `v` to the str.  That's not how join works.

```
>>> s = 'something'
>>> s.join('a')
'a'
```

`join` takes a list as an argument and joins its contents together, with the `str` instance as a separator.  Typically, the source string would actually be an empty string or a comma.

```
>>> s.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
'asomethingbsomethingc'
>>> ','.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])  # comma separation
'a,b,c'
>>> '-'.join(s)    # spell it out!
's-o-m-e-t-h-i-n-g'
```

#### How do I do it, then?

You append to strings using this syntax:

```
>>> s = s + 'a'
>>> s
'somethinga'
```

(Or the shorthand version:)

```
>>> s += 'a'
>>> s
'somethinga'
```

Comment: it does, right at the beginning? Or am I not understanding something?

Comment: @18166: What you're not understanding is the simple fact that Python strings are immutable.  You cannot change them "in-place."  You have to create a new string with the value you want.

Comment: I know they aren't immutable - I just had forgotten what that meant at the time (1 hour of programming isn't good for you, I swear!) but when I do that (s = s + 'a'), every time I do that in my program, it overights and doesnt carry over to another time I want to add to the string. Look at my edit above: